# HTML javascript valIdation not working

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this html with javascript validation form, but I don't know why it's not working. It's right now supposed to calculate the values of the two textboxes when the button is pressed. However nothing is happening. Code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Form Validator</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
//script here

function Validate()
{
var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
var emailRegex = /^[A-Za-z0-9._]*\@[A-Za-z]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,5}$/;
var     fname  = document.myform.FullName.value,        
        fmobile = document.myform.Mobile.value,
        femail = document.myform.Email.value,
        fpass1 = document.myform.pass1.value,
        fpass2 = document.myform.pass2.value,   
        faddress = document.myform.Address.value;

if( fname == "" )
   {
     document.myform.FullName.focus() ;
     document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the name";
     return false;
   }

    if (fmobile == "" )
    {
        document.myform.Mobile.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the Mobile Number";
        return false;
     }else if(!numbers.test(fmobile)){
        document.myform.Mobile.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid Mobile number";
        return false;
     }

          if (femail == "" )
    {
        document.form.Email.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the email";
        return false;
     }else if(!emailRegex.test(femail)){
        document.form.Email.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the valid email";
        return false;
     }


   if (fpass1 == "" )
    {
        document.myform.pass1.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the Password";
        return false;
     }else if(fpass1.length > 8){
        document.myform.pass1.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Password must be greater than 8 length";
        return false;
     }

      if (fpass2 == "" )
    {
        document.myform.pass2.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the Confirm Password";
        return false;
     }


     if(fpass1 !=  fpass2){
         document.myform.enterEmail.focus();
         document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "Passwords are not matching, re-enter again";
         return false;
         }


              if (faddress == "" )
    {
        document.myform.Address.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the Address";
        return false;
     }

         if(fname != '' && fmobile != '' && femail != '' && fpass1 != '' && fpass2 != '' && faddress != '' ){
            document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
            }



}


</script>// script ends here
</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate()" style="text-align:-moz-center;">
 // my html simple form start from here
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0" >
<tr>
    <td align="right">Full Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="FullName"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">Mobile</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Mobile"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right">Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Email"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="right">Password</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pass1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="right">Confirm Password</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pass2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="right">Address</td>
    <td><textarea cols="20" rows="5" name="Address"></textarea></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" "> <div id="errorBox"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Missing a " on this row `"enter the valid Mobile number`**"**`;`

Comment: It was the answer to his question. The button didn't work because he missed closing a string ...

Comment: Okay, but such questions shouldn't be answered. Flag them instead. OP should learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I didn't know. Thanks!